# Receive HTTP GET request on app initialization

Tags: angular

When my app is started for the first time, by calling localhost:4200, I want to extract some information from the HTTP request that requested the app in the first place.
I want to access the headers of the HTTP request that called the angular app, from inside the Angular app.
Do you have any ideas please about how can I do that?

I tried to call localhost:4200 and I want to read some headers that comes from my server.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can access the headers of the HTTP request that loaded your application by using Angular's HttpClient service. However, please note that you won't be able to directly access the headers of the initial request that loaded the Angular application at localhost:4200. Angular operates on the client-side and does not have access to the request headers sent by the server.
If you need to pass information from the server to your Angular application, you can do so by including the necessary data in the response from the server.

Here a Example

Express.js Example (Node.js server)

```html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/your-endpoint', (req, res) => {
    // Your server logic here

    // Include custom headers or data in the response
    res.setHeader('Custom-Header', 'Header-Value');
    res.json({ key: 'value', anotherKey: 'anotherValue' });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

In your Angular component, you can make an HTTP request to the server endpoint and access the custom headers and data:

```html
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

// ...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/your-endpoint').subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // Response body data
        const customHeader = data['Custom-Header']; // Access custom header
        console.log('Custom Header:', customHeader);
    });
}
```

This way, you can include the necessary information in the response from the server and access it in your Angular application.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your response, but in my case I want to access the headers of the HTTP request that called my angular app. Because when i call my localhost:4200 am redirected to a server that add some headers to my request and then load my angular app.